# Turning a complex jquery css selector into a context for caching

Tags: jquery, selector, extend

*After feedback, complete rewrite of the question.*

I have the following mark up :

```
<body>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>bla</p>
  <div>
    ... <!-- a thousand tags -->
  </div>

  <div id="do-not-modify-me">
   <!-- a hundred tags -->
  </div>

</body>
```

I can access to :

```
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>bla</p>
  <div>
    ... <!-- a thousand tags -->
  </div>
```

Using :

```
$('body > *:not(div#do-not-modify-me)');
```

I do that so I can get all the content of the body except the div with the id "do-not-modify-me".

Now, let's say that I want to build a function that let another programmer to select anything  in the body, just like the select with jquery. The other programmer should not modify div#do-not-modify-me, but he should not have to care about it neither.

`$('body > *:not(div#do-not-modify-me)')` will be called a lot of time, so we will cache it.

The *idea* is :

```
// TEST CODE

windows.new_body = $('body > *:not(div#do-not-modify-me)');

function select(selector) {
    return $(selector, windows.new_body);
}
```

So the other programmer should be able to do :

```
// TEST RESULT CODE
select("p").css("color", "red");
```

It would color in red all the `<p>` in the  body, but not the ones contained in div#do-not-modify-me.

The TEST CODE does not work, because currently, it applys css() on the children of the result of the context, not the result it self.

E.G :

```
select("p").css("color", "red");
```

Behaves like :

```
$('body > * p :not(div#do-not-modify-me)').css("color", "red");
```

While the desired result would be :

```
$('body > p :not(div#do-not-modify-me)').css("color", "red");
```

Note that :

```
$('body > * :not(div#do-not-modify-me)').parent().css("color", "red");
```

Does not work because the `<p>` div#do-not-modify-me turn into red.

How would you obtain the result in TEST RESULT CODE ? You can modify any part of the code.

Comment: It's not. I added some explanation. Hope it's clearer. If it's still cryptic, let me know.

Comment: I've take a look at your previous question, it's pretty unclear either. put here HTML markup and explain in examples different scenarios.

Comment: I'll be honoust, whith your latest comment to my answer. I don;t get what you want to do anymore. Could you rewrite your question, include some samples, because I really do not get it anymore.

Comment: LOL. OK. The more I write, the more I get it wrong. I am going to take me time to rewrite that properly. Thank you for spending time on this.

Comment: I've tried my last shot, if it won't help, think how to explain your self and fix you question.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just want to be able to perform operations on the result of the query without doing the query again. I think "cache" is a reasonable word for that.

Comment: THanks nosredna. English is not my mother tongue, so I can understand that I didn't make the best question it could be. I rewrote it all.

Comment: Be careful with the cache. If you make changes to the DOM it could become out-of-date.

Comment: Yeah. I just bet that the body tag will never be remove. The immutable div should not move either.

Comment: I revised my answer, I think it finally answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed all the previous EDIT's as they are no longer relevant, you can read them in the EDIT history.
**EDIT3**
Basically the problem is that you can not cache the selector. That is because the $() function returns matched objects, not un-matched objects. This means that using a cached selector will mean that the cache can get out of sync with the real DOM. I.e. in this simple page:

```
<div>
 <p>foo</p><p>bar</p>
</div>
<div class='bar'></div>
```

.

```
var context = $('body').children(':not(.bar)'); //this holds: <div><p>foo</p><p>bar</p></div>
$('div', context).append('<p class="x">HAI</p>'); 
//context still is <div><p>foo</p><p>bar</p></div> even though it should be
//<div><p>foo</p><p>bar</p><p class="x">HAI</p></div>
```

So you have to redo the selection everytime, bassicly you have two options here:

```
//reselect the non-editable area everytime
function select(selector) {
  return $(selector, $('body').children(':not(div#do-not-modify-me)') );
}
//or, check the selection against being in the reselectable area.
function select(selector){
  return $(selector).filter(function(){
     return $(this).parents(':not(div#do-not-modify-me)');
  });
}
```

You should try out yourself which one is faster. I do not think there is any other way to make sure you do not search in the #do-not-modify-me div.

Something else you could do to make this even more easy (and faster I think) is wrap the editable area in a div:

```
<body>
 <div id='modify-me'>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <!-- thousands of tags -->
 </div>
 <div id='do-not-modify-me'>
  <!--hundreds of tags -->
 </div>
</body>
```

Then you can just do

```
function select(selector) {
  return $(selector, $('#modify-me') );
}
```

Comment: Don't want the children, I need to  be able to select in the result of "context", just like I do with $() without anyparameter.

Comment: Maybe you will try to figure you question better? Write down what you exactly want, just in code like: "$("guess").do()" and etc.

Comment: The last sentence in your question is: "I will get all the children of the selected content. How would you modify that, so we can use it right away ?" In which I read: "How to immidiatly get the children, instead having to use $('*', context);

Comment: I think word "cache" was misused there.

Comment: That's a good start. But I wish to use $(selector, context) because the code is meant to be use for an external lib that is not supposed to know about the implementation.

Comment: somebody explain me what do you mean by children of result? you want explicit result? use context.get(i) where i is index of element in result set.

Comment: About your edit : I thought about this one, but getting the parent will give me body (or html). Finaly I select everything in it, and the not(div#do-not-modify-me) is invalidat. Interesting puzzle, isn't it ?

Comment: Interesting answer, @Pim Jager.

Comment: I will go for the solution where I wrap the stuff to select in a div. A brillant application of the Paul Arden's principle : http://www.amazon.co.uk/Whatever-You-Think-Opposite/dp/0141025719

Answer (score 1):

You said the code can be modified in any way, right? Why not just think of it as what you *do* want to search instead of what you *don't* want to search. Put the rest of the code in a `<div>` and just use that as the context. It's not going to win any elegance awards but it's simple and Gets The Job Done<sup>TM</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can just use 'context' directly, like so:

```
context = $('body > *:not(div#do-not-modify-me)');
context.doStuff();
```

Comment: LOL. Of course I can, but all the purpose is to cache it to avoid recalculate it everytime I use it. If the last function modify the jquery object, "context" will not be what I expect anymore ....

Comment: If you had phrased your question better, I might have been able to answer better, no need to downmod. pff

Comment: What exactly you are trying to cache? And why to down vote someone, because you cannot ask correct questions?

Comment: I don't downvote as a sanction, I down vote so people will no that that's not the answer. I understand I should modify the question. I am thinking about the way to make it better.

Comment: down voting people you reduce them a reputation, there is a comment to make the notion like that, you know it's much more polite way to let know to the person who tried to help you, event thought you question wasn't so perfect.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the extended explanation I'll try my shot:

```
context = $('body > *:not(div#do-not-modify-me)');
$("*:first",context);
```

You can even do:

```
  context = $('body > *:not(div#do-not-modify-me)');
  context.find( "*:first");
```

To get number of element you can do:

```
var len = context.length;
```

To access to element number i in the collection you can use:

```
context.get(i);
```

And there are tons of useful information on [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com), also read [this](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/extending-jquerys-selector-capabilities/) probably you will want to create your own selector.

**EDIT:**

After, I saw your recent update I think what you are looking for is for ability iterate over context results elements, so it could be done as I've mentioned here several time by:

```
    for ( var i = 0; i < context.length; ++i)
    {
         $( context[i]).method( );
         // do here you checks, adding, removing.
    }
```

This, doesn't look that clever, but should work, you can encapsulate this by extending $.fn and implementing function for your purpose.
    **EDIT #2:**
    
    Let's try another way:

```
    (function($)
    {
         $.fn.tagName = function( ) 
         {
             return this.get(0).tagName;
         };
         $.fn.pick = function( tag)
         {
             return this.filter( function( )
             {
                return $(this).tagName == tag;
             });
         };
    }

})(jQuery);
```

After this you can do contex.pick( "p"), so it will return you all paragraph inside your result set, but this code is incomplete, so you need to look some more into jquery code, for example to implement it in a way you will be able to use complete jquery functionality with pick function, probably you need to consider to use [xpath DOM parser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript).

Comment: $("*:first",context) gives me the first of the children of the result. So nope, it's not that. Removing something from body is harder than I thought.

Comment: Ok, my explanation may have not been so better than my first try because I don't want the first stuff of anything. Damn, where is my english teacher when I need it :-) ?

Comment: @Artem Barger: I don't think you need to go down the xpath road. jQuery bailed on xpath a long time ago (at least for the core library).

Comment: @Nosredna, I do think he is need to use xpath, what he is trying to do is out of regular usage of jquery, he is trying to get set of element collection and keep using selectors to lookup in it and he don't want just to iterate over it. So he definitely need to implement some more new functionality and since common jquery is not enough the use of xpath parser should be considered.